# UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate is not working when app is removed from background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, unusernotificationcenter

`UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` is not working when is remove from background. It is working fine while app stays in foreground and background.

**Here is code**

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {


        let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let profileViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SampleViewController") as! SampleViewController
        rootViewController.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

When app is remove from background delegate method is not called. Please help me out

Comment: If app is terminated through app Switcher then you can't receive notification in app

Comment: Is there any work around? To navigate app when is remove from background

Comment: so you want that notification when you re open an app?

Comment: An app cannot run any function when it is not running itself (and it is not running after it has been killed by user).

Comment: No, I want to navigate my app to view on click notification. When app is terminated.

Comment: So for that you don't need to do any thing!! your code will run when you click on notification.

Comment: It is not running when app is terminated

Comment: Andrey Chernukha Is there any around like launchoption

Comment: set notification delegate in app launch event

Answer (score 7):

When adding UserNotifications framework to a project, here are 5 things to check:

1) If you are dealing with remote notifications, be sure you have enabled that in your project's capabilities settings page of Xcode.

See [figure 1](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/dd2f56dbe9/f3327ebb-70be-4a12-9a76-b1a8badc0cd0.png)

If that gives you an error, you probably need to log into your apple developer account and create a key with push notification credentials. The end result gives you a .p8 file to download. The creation of this file will clear up the error. The file itself is needed on the server that sends push notifications to your app/device. If you need help with this, check out this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started).

2) Add import line to the top of your AppDelegate file

```
import UserNotifications
```

3) Add UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to your AppDelegate class declaration line.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {...
```

4) Set UNUserNotificationCenter delegate to self in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //...
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    //...
    return true
}
```

5) Add your delegate functions (if you want to use them)

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    NSLog("Application delegate method userNotificationCenter:didReceive:withCompletionHandler: is called with user info: %@", response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    //...
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    NSLog("userNotificationCenter:willPresent")
    //...
    completionHandler([.alert])
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

check `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?` method. When user taps a notification banner (and the app is terminated) the app is started, this method is called and `launchOptions` contains notification info. Therefore you can understand (by checking the `launchOptions`) that the app is launched by tapping on notification banner and navigate user wherever you want to

Comment: i tried like this
let localnotification = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.localNotification] as? [String: Any]
        if localnotification != nil {
            
        
        }
        else {
            NSLog("//////////////////////////Normal launch")
        }

Comment: It is deprecated now for local notification

Comment: so we are talking about local notifications? It would be great if you indicated that in your post. I haven't dealt with local notifications for a long time. why do you think it is deprecated? where did your read this? and even if it is deprecated you can still use it, it is not recommended though

Comment: It is showing the deprecation warning in code and i am using it but no luck

Comment: what kind of deprecation warning it shows? where? and what do you mean no luck? does the launch options contain any information when it is launched by tapping on notification banner? can you just print it and see?

Comment: 'localNotification' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:]